# Is there any resource where you can look up a board position and read a number of suggested moves?

Tags: strategy, tactics

Is there any resource where you could just plug in the positions of all the pieces on the board and, for example, see an annotated page where different people or computer-generated bots have analyzed the strengths of various possible moves?

Comment: « People have ... » Do you know how many possible positions there are? It’s trivial to get a computer eval with suggested lines. You’d need to pay a few very skilled people a good amount, or crowdsource and be willing to sort the dirt from the gold...

Comment: I do not think so at least if you are considering most positions. Even in the opening, you can plug in a position, but you just see all the moves that have been played, but sans annotations.

Comment: I think this is a very reasonable question. You do have annotated games online (e.g. at chessgames.com). In principle it should be possible to link to those pages from a search page. I understand that it won't be easy because those pages are not search friendly (for this purpose), but still it could be done. I am thinking of something along the lines of linguee, where you can enter a word and find it used in different context on various pages.

Comment: @user1583209 I agree it is a reasonable question, and that it is technologically possible, but at the same time, I just do not think it exists right now. I also do think that it would be problematic to get a vast collection together where "different" people annotated the games because the annotations are copyrighted. You could certainly get a bunch of weak players to add their comments, but there are only so many games that get annotated by multiple strong players, and it is simply because they are usually the games of elite players in elite events, and typically, they are paid to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you get ChessBase, there are a number of features that are available when setting up a certain position:

1) With a reference database, you can see the moves chosen in all the games from that position. These moves can be ranked in various ways (e.g., number of games played, rating of players, etc).

2) When turning on an engine to analyze the position, you can see previous engine evaluations of the position (stored from people who analyzed it before). This assumes you're connected to the internet, and that they were as well (so that their engine evaluation could be saved on the cloud).

3) The LiveBook feature allows you to see the number of visits certain moves from that position have had by people who analyzed previously (again, assuming these people were connected to the cloud at the time). This is often a good way to see what the best moves are objectively, as well as the most popular moves played in games (since people could be following a game, which is why they looked at a particular move).